# Linux test environment in USB key (apache + php + git)?

Tags: php, linux, git, usb, virtual

Does any one knows a convenient solution how to run or boot linux from USB stick or drive. I usually work on windows os, but need to test a web application on Linux environment. Currently I don't want to install linux on my local drive. Booting or starting a virtual image from windows or from usb would be a perfect solution.

Linux need to have (git + webserver + php + xdebug + Xwindows)
not sure about Xwindows how it will affect perfomance if it will start  virtually.

Comment: You should probably ask this on [Superuser](https://superuser.com/), as it´s off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can install basic Linux (or ubuntu or whatever) on a usb stick as you would usually install it anyway. The only real important thing is for your computer to support booting from said USB. You'll obviously have to make sure the USB is in the right format and such.

From this point on, you can boot into Linux and install it however you want. You can simply install the webserver, the git, etc. as you would any other linux installation.

It seems to me creating a virtual machine would be easier, but hey, to each their own.

For me, [USBwebserver](http://www.usbwebserver.net/) has always worked wonders. Then again, whenever I need an actual external server I just use my live server.

Anyways, back on topic, this should instruct you properly on how to install Linux on a USB flash drive:
http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Install-a-Linux-OS-in-your-USB-Flash-Drive-/

- I would personally recommend using USB 3.0 as it's a lot faster, unless this gives issues with linux itself.

Now, once you've installed linux and you can boot into it, simply google on how to install a webserver on Linux. It will work like any other regular installation and it's quite easy. There's a *lot* of tutorials out there. You could use [LAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)) or [XAMMP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) as predefined solutions.

Tailor it to your needs, and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

If a virtual image would be perfect for you, then consider installing VirtualBox and use it for this.   If you have the space, this would be a very good solution.

If you want to reboot your machine to Linux, then Ubuntu has a very nice Live-CD facility, where you can use a USB-drive to store things on.  You could also install Linux on an external USB-harddrive and run directly from that (much faster).